# Urn with replacement, 3 colours, drawing all colours

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have a problem with the following exercise.
Given an urn with $w$ white balls, $r$ red balls and $b$ black balls, so in total there are $w+r+b$ balls.
Now $3$ balls are drawn from the urn with replacement.
What is the probability to get each colour.

I tried to solve it this way: It is equally likely to draw each ball (not taking care of the colour). The number of different ways to draw balls with replacement is described by combinations with replacement, say $C_{n,k}^{(r)} = \binom{n+k-1}{k}$. The probability should be therefore:
\begin{align*}
\frac{C_{w,1}^{(r)} C_{r,1}^{(r)} C_{b,1}^{(r)}}{C_{w+r+b,3}^{(r)}} = \frac{w r b}{\binom{w+r+b+2}{3}}.
\end{align*}
As I am highly sceptical about such exercises I wrote a short script testing the probability. The result is that either my mathematical approach or my short script is wrong.
As I am pretty sure that my mathematical approach is wrong I would like to know why. Why can't I get the probability with this method?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of drawing one of each colour in three draws with replacement is actually:$$\dfrac{3! r wb}{(r+w+b)^3}$$

Your formula simplifies to: $$\dfrac{3!rwb}{(r+w+b+2)(r+w+b+1)(r+w+b)}$$

The reason this is not the same is that $\mathrm C^{(\mathrm r)}_{n,k}$ counts the number of distinct *combinations* of $k$ items extracted from a set of $n$ items *without distinguishing by order*.   These are *not equally probable* outcomes.   So taking the ratio of ways to select combinations with replacement for one from each colour, against ways to select combinations with replacement for three from all balls, will *not* yield a valid probability measure.

For instance $\mathrm C^{\rm (r)}_{3,2}=6$ counts the ways to extract two balls from three, $\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet, \color{red}\bullet\color{blue}\bullet, \color{red}\bullet\color{green}\bullet, \color{blue}\bullet\color{blue}\bullet, \color{blue}\bullet\color{green}\bullet, \color{green}\bullet\color{green}\bullet.$    Where as there would be $3^3$ equally probable ways: $\color{red}\bullet\color{red}\bullet, \color{red}\bullet\color{blue}\bullet, \color{red}\bullet\color{green}\bullet, \color{blue}\bullet\color{red}\bullet, \color{blue}\bullet\color{blue}\bullet, \color{blue}\bullet\color{green}\bullet, \color{green}\bullet\color{red}\bullet, \color{green}\bullet\color{blue}\bullet,  \color{green}\bullet\color{green}\bullet.$

Answer (score 0):

You have these valid combination to get all three colors 
$(w,b,r),(w,r,b),(r,w,b),(r,b,w),(b,r,w),(b,w,r)$

for the first case : we need to get a white color then black then red.
so the probability is $p_1 = \frac{w}{w+b+r} * \frac{b}{w+b+r-1} * \frac{r}{w+b+r-2} = \frac{6 b r w}{\binom{b+r+w }{3}}$

you will do the same for $p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6$ and then adding them together will result $6 p_1 = \frac{36 b r w}{\binom{b+r+w }{3}}$

hope its what you are looking for

Comment: This looks very good, thank you very much for your answer! However, I would love to know why my approach does not work to fully understand this concept.